# What if the partition of India were bottom-up

Tags: alternate-history, politics

In 1947 suppose that, instead of attempting to draw a fair line between Muslims and non-Muslims, British India has a referendum asking each village, “With which of your neighbors (including native states) would you merge?”  Do the most favored mergers (skipping those that would create enclaves), and ask again ... until no further mergers are approved.  (Increase the threshold of approval at each step.)

The disadvantage is that some ambitious parties paint the process as a last effort to keep India divided and weak.

The advantage, as I see it, is that the people decide by *their own* criteria how to divide themselves, which may be on religious or ethnic lines, or not; I suspect links of commerce often outweigh such differences, but that's my own ignorance and bias talking.  In any case, fewer refugees!

The immediate result is, let's say, twenty to a hundred post-British states.
Of the many native states, some have grown, and some are quickly seized by their bigger new neighbors.

What happens next?  What does India look like thirty years later, assuming no British (or Chinese or ...) interference?

(Prompted by [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59995/what-would-have-happened-to-the-world-if-the-sepoy-mutiny-of-1857-had-suceeded) about the Sepoy Rebellion.)

Comment: "What happens next" is a very broad question. Are you asking about "next" on hourly, yearly, or millennial time scales? From a social, military, or economic perspective? Assuming no external influence from Britain or other countries? I suspect there are an infinite number of alternatives, so we'll need some restrictions to narrow down the possibilities. I've voted to place your question on hold until you get a chance to [edit] it so you don't get swamped with unhelpful answers.

Comment: Doesn't look like this would create much difference in the country boundaries, just in who to blame for them.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_India#/media/File:Brit_IndianEmpireReligions3.jpg

Comment: @Cyn, I explicitly reject the assumption that majorities choose to join with *all* their co-religionists.  Why not, for example, Dravidians vs Aryans?

Comment: Anything's possible but I'd guess almost everyone would vote for the option that doesn't require them to move.

Comment: You fail to take caste divisions into account. The upper castes would join forces and force the lower castes (~40%+ of the population, at a conservative estimate) to vote according to their dictates or simply not be allowed near the voting centre. Minorities need not show up.

Comment: @nzaman Sure, I don't assume that the voting is clean enough to please Jimmy Carter. Do the dominant castes strongly favour grand unification on religious lines? (If so, why was India so fragmented when the colonizers arrived?)

Comment: This is a grossly counterfactual question. The British *did not* want to partition India. They thought that it was just fine at it was. The partition was driven by Indian (mostly Muslim) politicians. And when the British left, [*most* of the Indian subcontinent was *not* included](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:India_and_Pakistan_15_Aug_1947.png) in the gloriously independent states India and Pakistan, but rather continued under the traditional rulers. India and Pakistan incorporated the rest of territory post-independence, by various peaceful and not so peaceful means.

Comment: @AlexP, thank you for that map!

Comment: @AntonSherwood: The local influential members of the upper castes would choose whatever option maximised their self interest, which would probably vary wildly from region to region. The Punjab, for instance, might favour staying with Rajastan and Gujarat because they wanted strong trading links for their agricultural produce, while Delhi might want to have nothing to do with them.

Comment: @AlexP “You want a partition, Mr Jinnah? I'll give you a partition!”